# Remove part of a string value from a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Working with a Pandas data frame and want to be able to drop the Name ID in each row of the Players column starting with the '\'

New to python and pandas, assuming this is probably an easy fix with a line or two of code but I cant seem to crack it.

```
file_open=open('2000_2019_All_Pro.csv')
df_AP2000 = pd.read_csv(file_open)
df_counts = df_AP2000['Player'].value_counts()
df_counts.to_frame()
df_counts.drop(df_counts.index[[0]], axis=0, inplace=True)
df_counts.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Player', 'Player': 'Frequency'})
```

[Data frame and code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roIXL.jpg)

Comment: Please post code as `formatted text`, not images.

Comment: **[No Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/)** of code or data. Always provide a [mre] with code, **data, errors, current output, and expected output**, as **[formatted text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)**. If relevant, plot images are okay. Please see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Try `df_counts['Player'] = df_counts['Player'].str.split('\\').str[0]`

Comment: @ScottBoston it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using string manipulation with `split`:

```
df_counts['Player'] = df_counts['Player'].str.split('\\').str[0]
```